# How Entity Framework know to which class is take to add migration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My question is very simple, I am using Entity Framework with asp.net MVC.

I am not sure this question is helpful or not, but I have a doubt.

How entity framework should known, that he has to add migration for which class, why EF will not generate migration for ViewModel class ?

**I am just want to know how EF will differentiated between ViewModel.cs class and Model.cs class and add migration only for model.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it checks which classes have been added to a DbContext.

```
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure; 

namespace MigrationsDemo 
{ 
    public class BlogContext : DbContext 
    { 
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } 
    } 

    public class Blog 
    { 
        public int BlogId { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
    } 
}
```

Blog will now be considered with the migration. Please see this link for more information on code-first migrations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are some places that you can add configuration to Entity Framework,  but in its basic form, it iterates the properties on your `DbContext` class (with a public `get`), and considers all properties of type `IDbSet` to be a part of the data model.

The properties do not have to have a `set`. For example, this is a valid entity definition in `DbContext` that EF will pick up and generate Migration for:

```
public IDbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities
{
    get { return Set<MyEntity>(); }
}
```